# Python: Matching Two Columns from Two Files

Tags: python, database

I want to create a python script that matches the first 2 columns from an input file (file 1)

```
10000D 10000R
10003D 10003R
```

and matches these two columns to columns 2 and 4 in another input file (file 2) where the dataset is kept.

```
0 10000D 0 10000R 0.05
0 10001D 0 10001D 0.06
0 10003D 0 10003R 0.09
```

Once these columns are matched, I would like to print out the rows where the columns from file 1 that matched with file 2 are saved in a new output file.  The output file should look like this:

```
0 10000D 0 10000R 0.05
0 10003D 0 10003R 0.09
```

My code looks like this:

```
#Python code for pi-hats extraction

#!/usr/bin/python

#open and read file to read from (F1), file to match to (F2), File to write and save to (F3)

F1 = open("File_1", "r") #File_1 is original file, has 2 columns
F2 = open("File_2", "r") #where dataset is kept
F3 = open("File_3", "w") #where matches are stored

for match1 in sorted(F1):
    if match1 in F2:
        F3.write(match)
        F3.close()
exit
```

However, when I run this code, I'm not getting any matches.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

DM

Update:
The original file 2 looks something like this:

```
0  10000_D   0  10000_R AB     0  1.2345  0.1234  0.0000  0.0000  -1  0.765432  0.05  1.2345

0  10001_D   0  10001_R AB     0  1.2345  0.1234  0.0000  0.0000  -1  0.876543  0.06  1.3456

0  10003_D   0  10003_R AB     0  1.2345  0.1234  0.0000  0.0000  -1  0.987654  0.09  1.4567
```

Maybe the spacing has something to do with it? I think the formatting might have changed when I put it to excel.

Comment: No debugging possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open("File_1", "r") as F1:  #File_1 is original file, has 2 columns
    # split the file using a space as delimiter and read it to the memory:
    F1_d = sorted(csv.reader(F1, delimiter=' ')) 

with open("File_2", "r") as F2:  #where dataset is kept
    # split the file using space again, and read it to a dictionary
    # structure indexed by second and forth columns:
    F2_d = {(row[1], row[3]): row for row in csv.reader(F2, delimiter=' ')}

with open("File_3", "w") as F3: #where matches are stored
    for match1 in F1_d: 
        if tuple(match1) in F2_d: # search for a match using the index defined
            F3.write(' '.join(F2_d[tuple(match1)]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried running this but got the following error message:             
                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "DR_scripting3.txt", line 11, in <module>
        F2_d = {(row[1], row[3]): row for row in csv.reader(F1, delimiter=' ')}
    TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator

Comment: That is a typo, it should be `F2`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Diego try it now

Comment: Hi,I tried it again and I got the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DR_scripting3.py", line 15, in <module>
    if match1 in F2_d: # search for a match using the index defined
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Oh sure, forgot you need tuples to search the dict. Try it now @Diego

Comment: Hi, I still have the tuple problem.  I tried converting File_1 into a tuple at line 6 like so:    F1_d = sorted(csv.reader(tuple(F1), delimiter=' '))  #turn search list into tuple to search dictionary                However, I'm still getting the error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DR_scripting3.py", line 15, in <module>
    if match1 in F2_d: # search for a match using the index defined
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'                                                                                                I don't think that F2_d is supposed to be tuple right?

Comment: @Diego I edited the answer added the conversion to tuple in the match line `if tuple(match1) in F2_d:` please try the code as listed in the answer

Comment: Ok, now the code runs without errors but, there is nothing in the output.  I'll need to check my File_2.

Comment: I created `File_1` and `File_2` with the contents you listed in your question, and ran the latest code from the edited answer. The `File_3` is generated with the expected results! It is working fine here on my end.

Comment: @Diego I can't quite tell but maybe you have tabs instead of spaces, try changing all delimiters to \t `delimiter='\t'`

Comment: I think spacing might be the issue. It seems that when I moved Files 1 and 2 to excel, the formatting changed a little bit.  I have made the updates for it.

Comment: I now have the following error. Upon further inspection, I've also noticed that File 1 columns are separated by tabs.                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DR_scripting3.py", line 11, in <module>
    F2_d = {(row[1], row[3]): row for row in csv.reader(F2, delimiter='\t')}
  File "DR_scripting3.py", line 11, in <dictcomp>
    F2_d = {(row[1], row[3]): row for row in csv.reader(F2, delimiter='\t')}
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: the error means you have a row in File 2 that doesn't have the columns 2 and 4